# If the hydroxide ion is such a poor leaving group then why does water dissociate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Water dissociates into the hydroxide and hydronium ions but, why does this happen if the hydroxide ion is such a poor leaving group. Alcohols don't undergo $\ce{S_{N}1}$ reactions because the hydroxide ion doesn't dissociate so why does it happen in water?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only 1 in 10,000,000 water molecules dissociate.

HI, HBr and HCl fully dissociate, and I-, Br-, and Cl- and are much better leaving groups.

Comment: what is it exactly that makes the hydroxide ion such a bad leaving group?

Comment: Weak bases (conjugate bases of strong acids) are good leaving groups.  Strong bases are bad leaving groups.  H-, CH3-, etc. would be even worse than OH-.

Comment: Is SH- a good leaving group?

Comment: I would expect SH- to be a poor leaving group, but not quite as bad as OH-, based upon the pKa of H2S being 6.9.  I don't have any personal experience with it though.

Comment: @DavePhD You are avoiding the issue there I think, because the next logical question would be: "Then why is hydroxide such a strong base?". This question is more or less equivalent to what OP asked.

Comment: @Jori I don't follow what you are saying.  Strong bases are bad leaving groups.  H-, CH3-, and NH2- are even stronger bases than OH-, so they are even worse leaving groups.  I-, Cl-, and Br- are very weak bases, so they are much better leaving groups than OH-.

Comment: @DavePhD I meant that when OP asked why SH- is a bad leaving group answering with: "because it is not very acidic" is just moving the issue around a bit. It is like saying well SH- is not really acidic because it is a bad leaving group. It is a bit nitpicking from me and I do not question your abilities in anyway, but you see my point? If you truly want to understand why e.g. OH- is a strong base you should go into detail about the structure of OH-. That is, a better answer would be "well OH- is strongly basic because the oxyanion is a hard nucleophile and has a large electronegativity.

Comment: @yJori, yes I understand now, your explanation is more complete

Answer (score 1):

Water dissociating into H+ and OH- isn't the same concept as free OH- leaving. A more accurate comparison would be forming NaOH by dropping Na metal in water, because in that case, OH- leaves water to become part of a new molecule as opposed to just ionizing in solution for a second before it becomes full water again.

Alcohols are very capable of SN1. Water is the leaving group as it is obviously protonated first. Benzyl alcohol to benzyl chloride, t-butanol to t-butyl bromide, etc.